# How to connect to the Neo4j importer using a Local DBMS from Neo4j Desktop

Tags: neo4j

I am currently using a Neo4j database on Neo4j desktop, I want to use the Neo4j importer but I do not know where to find the credentials asked for by the Neo4j importer, where can I find this?

Comment: There are many ways to import data into neo4j. How specifically are you trying to import?

Comment: I am using the Neo4j importer tool, and before using this tool it asks for connection credentials, which I do not know where to find for my local Neo4j database on my desktop

Comment: Please provide a URL to the "import tool", or its documentation.

Comment: https://data-importer.graphapp.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Data Importer](https://neo4j.com/docs/aura/aurads/importing-data/data-importer/) that you are trying to use is intended to be used with Neo4j [Aura](https://neo4j.com/cloud/platform/aura-graph-database/), not local database installations. It requires the server to be configured to use SSL (so it only supports the `bolt+s` and `neo4j+s` URI schemes).

You should use a different approach to [import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/neo4j-admin-import/) data into local DB installations.